# JS get max first n values from a string

Tags: javascript, string, loops

I need to capture maximum 5 elements of a `string`. However if there are less than 5, then I just need how many there are there.

```
var y = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10'        
//desired result: 
var out = '1,2,3,4,5' // please note there is no trailing comma



var y = '1,2,3'
//desired result: 
var out = '1,2,3'
```

My code:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    x += y;
     x = x + ",";
   }


Write(x);
```

Comment: What's the value of `x` and `y` in your snippet?

Comment: In your first two examples one has spaces stripped, the other doesn't. Please make sure both examples follow the same ruleset.

Comment: `y` is the string, and `x` is the variable that I want to store the output of the resulting output string

Comment: well is the list of numbers always in order?

Comment: @epascarello its always in the correct order that I need to have them. But, it could also be `6,5,4,3,2,1`. In which case still need the first 5 element i.e. `6,5,4,3,2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple method will do. The below splits the string by `,` then takes either `n` elements or the total length if it is less than `n` and then rejoins the values with a comma

```js
const getNValues = (str, n) => {
   const values = str.split(",");
   const res = values.slice(0, Math.min(values.length,n))
   return res.join(",");
}


console.log(getNValues("1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9",5));
console.log(getNValues("1,2,3",5));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var string = '1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10';
var out = (string.match(/^([0-9],? ?){0,5}/)[0] || '').replace(/, ?$/, '');
console.log(out)
```

[EDIT] Explanation
`.match(^([0-9],? ?){0,5}/g)`:

- start at the begging `^`
- match numbers `[0-9]`
- then a comma if any and a space if any `,? ?`.
- match this expression 0 to 5 times `{0, 5}`

Comment: This seems to work quite nicely! However, if the string is five or less, than it doesn't capture the last element. For example `1, 2, 3, 4` then the output is `1, 2, 3`

Comment: Updated, forgot a little `?` on the `, ?` expression

Comment: @apples-oranges ooh ouch. regex for this task is _total overkill!_

Comment: @apples-oranges if you are looking for performance it is indeed an overkill, I posted this as an alternative as other solutions were already given but I would advise to use the split method for performance and readability

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple function to do that

```js
function getMaxLen(str) {
  if(typeof str != 'string') return null;
  str = str.split(',');
  return str.slice(0, 5).join(',');
}

console.log(getMaxLen('1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10'))
console.log(getMaxLen('1,2,3'))
```

Comment: Nice one! That works perfectly as well :)